# Vigenere Cipher in C: Incomplete Encryption

Tags: c, loops, encryption, cs50, vigenere

**A general explanation of the Vigenere Cipher:**

The Vigenere Cipher is a method of encryption that is similar to the Caesar Cipher. This Cipher takes in a word as an argument and interprets the alphabets of the word as follows- a as 0, b as 1, c as 2 and so on.

So if your input key is abc and you want something like "hi hello" to be encrypted, the output would entail h remaining the same, i shifting by 1 place, h shifting by 2 places, e again remaining the same (as it is being shifted by 0), l shifting by 1 place, the other l by 2 and so on so forth.

The basic idea is that each letter shifts by the corresponding letter in the argument and the spaces and other punctuation marks are ignored. If the argument is shorter than the message (as it is in most cases), the argument simply loops around the message.

---

**My problem:**

My message is just being encrypted by the first alphabet of the Vignere Cipher.

For example, `./vc bc` ----> `message: ABCDE ABCDE` becomes `BCDEF BCDEF`. In other words, the entire message is just being shifted by the value of b when it should instead be shifted by the value of bc (+1 for the first alphabet and +2 for every other alphabet.)

I don't understand why is this happening despite being within a loop.

**CODE:**

```
# include <cs50.h> 
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string word = argv[1];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (argc != 2 || isalpha(word[j]) == false)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid command line argument! \n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if (isalpha(word[j]))
    {
        printf("Message: "); 
        string message = GetString();

        for (int n = strlen(message); i < n; i++)
        {
               int plaintext = message[i];
               int ciphertext = word[j]; 
               int uppcb = (plaintext - 65 + ciphertext - 65);
               int upcipher1 = (uppcb) % 26;
               int uplc = (plaintext - 65 + ciphertext - 97);
               int upcipher2 = (uplc) % 26;
               int lopcb = (plaintext - 97 + ciphertext - 97);
               int locipher1 = (lopcb) % 26;
               int lolp = (plaintext - 97 + ciphertext - 65);
               int locipher2 = (lolp) % 26;

                if (isupper(word[j]) && isupper(message[i])) 
                {
                    j = (j+1)%strlen(word);
                    int upcode = (upcipher1 + 65); 
                    printf("%c", upcode);
                }
                else if (isupper(message[i]) && islower(word[j]))
                {
                    j = (j+1)%strlen(word);
                    int upcode1 = (upcipher2 + 65);
                    printf("%c", upcode1);
                }
                else if (islower(message[i]) && islower(word[j]))
                {
                    j = (j+1)%strlen(word);
                    int locode = (locipher1 + 97); 
                    printf("%c", locode);
                }
                else if (islower(message[i]) && isupper(word[j]))
                {
                    j = (j+1)%strlen(word);
                    int locode1 = (locipher2 +97);
                    printf("%c", locode1);
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf("%c", message[i]);
                }          
        }
        printf("\n");     
    }

}
```

Comment: You never increment `j` in your loop. The bottom of the loop should have something to the effect of `j = (j+1) % strlen(word);` (and I would advise pre-calculating that `strlen()`, as it isn't subject to change). Or modify the `for` loop increment step to be `++i, j=(j+1)%strlen(word)`, same advice on caching the `strlen()`. Either way will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for the first word now but not for the rest of it. It still increments everything after the first 'space' by the first alphabet of the first argument. If you don't mind me asking, could you please explain to me how exactly is the part- `(j+1) % strlen(word);` working? I have a basic idea but its very fuzzy in my head and I'm not sure if its correct. I will try amending this code once I understand what exactly is happening. Thanks! :)

Comment: It ensures j is always in the range of `0`...(`strlen(word)-1`). When `(j+1)` would land on the string length of `word` (and thus the terminating null) it resets to zero and starts over with the first letter in `word`.  For more info, lookup the *modulo* operator in your text. Best of luck.